# determining the right grammatical form

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

below is a question from Manhattan gmat.

Why are these considered wrong:

"the winner was determined through a coin toss"

and

"the winner was determined from a coin toss".

I cannot make out what exactly and why!

Comment: In speech, both these forms are acceptable to me, though I would prefer to use "through" over "from", and I would prefer "the winner was determined _by means of_ a coin toss" over both. Not sure why these would be considered ungrammatical.

Comment: your answer satisfies me because I also think the same. but there should be a reason as to why my tutor said it was wrong. to be precise, he said it was a blooper and left it to me to find out why.

Comment: As pointed out, the more common preposition for passive agents is _by_. However, that doesn't absolve the question writer from the fatal sin of asking the wrong question. The reason they're "considered wrong" is that they've been taken out of context and may bear traces of speech patterns that are not approved by those who consider themselves the upper classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct preposition is "by."

> The winner was determined by a coin toss.

"By" implies that the coin toss is **the means** used to determine the winner.

E.g. she carved the statue by hand from basswood and oak.

Now, if you say:

> The winner was determined through a coin toss.

It means that the coin toss is **the process** used in determining the winner.

E.g. the effect of most medicinal substances can only be determined **through** experimentation.

As for:

> The winner was determined from a coin toss.

It implies that you can **deduce** the winner by looking at the coin toss.

E.g. some people think that your personality can be determined **from** your handwriting.

That being said, the difference is purely idiomatic. And so, it personally doesn't make any sort of difference to my ear whether you say the winner was determined "by," "through," or "from" a coin toss, as long as the general idea conveyed here, i.e. the coin toss determined the winner -- is unequivocally perceived.

Comment: _By_ is certainly the usual choice here, but it does not reference the cause of the victory, but rather the instrument / method used [here, to decide on a winner]. 'She carved it by hand.' 'He worked it out by finding the volume of the object then multiplying ...' 'By' in the sense of 'by means of'. **Not** 'by' as in 'The safety lamp was invented by Davy'.